# How set value in constant into struct c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constants

I can not assign a value to a constant within a structure, follow the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
  float intensity;
} PointXYZI;

typedef struct structParent{
  int x;
  int y;
  const PointXYZI* xyzi;
} structParent;

int main()
{

  float o = 10.f, p = 5.0f, z = 96.0f;

  PointXYZI points = {o, p, z};

  const structParent *data = {0,0, &points};

  std::cout << " *-* " << data.xyzi->c << std::endl;
  std::cout << " *-* " << points.a << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error with this code:

error: scalar object ‘data’ requires one element in initializer const structParent *data = {0,0, &points};

Thank you...

Comment: `const structParent *data` is a pointer - you probably want just an object `const structParent data`

Comment: Yes, but  I have to use data as a pointer in a function

Comment: You could use the address-of operator to pass it into the function (`&data`) - just like you do with `points`. Or if you insist on keeping it as a raw pointer you have to create an object using `new structParent`

Comment: Follow function someFunction(const dwLidarDecodedPacket* packet, dwLidarAccumulatorHandle_t obj);

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say with that comment

Comment: the function that receives as parameter the "DATA"

Comment: I don't see how it is relevant or how it contradicts my previous comments. My second comment already contains the solution to your problem

Comment: Yeah sorry, I will delete it.

Comment: Fun fact: C++ benefited greatly from decades of C programming. One of these benefits is you do not need `typedef struct { ... } PointXYZI;` to avoid typing `struct` every time you refer to a `struct`. The C++ compiler knows the `struct` is a `struct`, so you can get away with `struct PointXYZI{ ... } ;` and use to `PointXYZI` without additional adornment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explained by example version of @UnholySheep's answer is the following.

```
void someFunc(const structParent &x)
//                             ^^^^^^
{
  std::cout << " @_@ " << x.xyzi->c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

  float o = 10.f, p = 5.0f, z = 96.0f;

  PointXYZI points = {o, p, z, 0};
  //                        ^^^^^
  const structParent data = {0,0, &points};
  //                ^^^
  std::cout << " *-* " << data.xyzi->c << std::endl;
  std::cout << " *-* " << points.a << std::endl;

  someFunc(data);
  //      ^^^^^^^
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. But that not solved my problem. I'll post later the solution, following @UnholySheep